# 'SqlBulkCopy' was not found

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

When I try to create a following stored procedure in a new server, I get error

> Msg 6528, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_BulkCopy, Line 3
>   Assembly 'SqlBulkCopy' was not found in the SQL catalog of database 'master'.

Code:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_BulkCopy]    Script Date: 08/22/2012 23:32:59 ******/
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_BulkCopy]
    @sourceServer [nvarchar](255),
    @sourceDatabase [nvarchar](255),
    @sourceSelectQuery [nvarchar](4000),
    @destinationServer [nvarchar](255),
    @destinationDatabase [nvarchar](255),
    @destinationTable [nvarchar](255),
    @FlagKeepIdentity [bit],
    @throwExceptionOnErrors [bit],
    @SourceTrusted [bit],
    @DestTrusted [bit],
    @SourceUser [nvarchar](255),
    @SourcePass [nvarchar](255),
    @DestUser [nvarchar](255),
    @DestPass [nvarchar](255)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [SqlBulkCopy].[StoredProcedures].[usp_BulkCopy]
GO
```

How do I overcome this? I am not sure what an assembly is and if it is indeed a real issue.

Thanks for your time..

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear: that assembly `SqlBulkCopy` that you are referencing in `EXTERNAL NAME [SqlBulkCopy].[StoredProcedures].[usp_BulkCopy]` isn't present in the `master` database - so you need to load it into the master database first with `CREATE ASSEMBLY`

Comment: This stored procedure of yours obviously references a .NET CLR assembly where the function has been implemented. For this to work, that assembly needs to be present in the database where you create your stored procedures - and it's not, as the error shows. You need to **first** load that assembly into the database (using `CREATE ASSEMBLY`) **before** you can make references to it. Google + read up on "SQL CLR integration" or "SQL CLR stored procedures" to learn more about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Marc S. It was the assembly.

Hope it might help someone else. here is the details of what I did.

I found the assembly from another DB server and ran it on this server like this:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [SqlBulkCopy]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 
[CODE in Hexadecimals-this would be unique I think]
```

Then I had to do this:

```
ALTER DATABASE [master] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

and then this:

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled',1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled'  -- make sure it took
GO
```

That was all. it worked fine:

To make sure the assembly is installed, you can run this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies
```